# NSInvalidArgumentException: *** -[NSConcreteMutableData initWithCapacity:]: absurd capacity: 3794795864, maximum size: 2147483648 bytes

Tags: ios, nsmutabledata

My iOS app is downloading a very large zip file (of 3.79GB) using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking). My app also used Flipboard's [FLEX](https://github.com/Flipboard/FLEX) library 2.2 to monitor the network traffic. A user reported that once the app trigger the download request, the app crashes with the following stacktrace:

```
Crashed Thread

0   CoreFoundation 0x22c6010b __exceptionPreprocess + 124
1   libobjc.A.dylib 0x22406e17 objc_exception_throw + 36
2   CoreFoundation 0x22c60051 +[NSException raise:format:] + 110
3   Foundation 0x233bed7d -[NSConcreteMutableData initWithCapacity:] + 106
4   previewer 0x001e9c3d __86-[FLEXNetworkObserver(NSURLConnectionHelpers) connection:didReceiveResponse:delegate:]_block_invoke (FLEXNetworkObserver.m:946)
5   libdispatch.dylib 0x227d9b5b _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8
6   libdispatch.dylib 0x227e675b _dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$mp + 1756
7   libdispatch.dylib 0x227e5d99 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 282
8   libdispatch.dylib 0x227e8495 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 394
9   libdispatch.dylib 0x227e8305 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 94
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x22997b29 _pthread_wqthread + 1022
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x22997718 start_wqthread + 6
```

The crash reason:

> NSInvalidArgumentException: *** -[NSConcreteMutableData
>   initWithCapacity:]: absurd capacity: 3794795864, maximum size:
>   2147483648 bytes

and it occurs at the following lines at `FLEXNetworkObserver`:

```
if (response.expectedContentLength < 0) {
    dataAccumulator = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
} else {
    dataAccumulator = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:(NSUInteger)response.expectedContentLength];
}
```

He was using iPad 3 and he said he cannot reproduce the problem using his newer iPad mini 3. May I know if that is caused by the 32-bit limitation of older iPad model (in this case iPad 3)? What is the reason causing the crash?

I will disable FLEX network debugging as a workaround to this problem.

**Update**

I can successfully download the file after disabling FLEX by  `[[FLEXManager sharedManager] setNetworkDebuggingEnabled:NO];`, so that's not related to AFNetworking at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My iOS app is downloading a very large zip file

The fact that an NSMutableData is being set aside to hold it suggests that the plan here is not to *download* the file but to treat it as *data* to be held the whole time in *memory*. That is very wrong, esp. since your app could well crash if it tried to hold such a large object in memory. A true *download* would download *to disk* and virtually no memory would have to be set aside.

Comment: I could tell you how to do that using NSURLSession, but I've no knowledge of AFNetworking so I leave it to you to figure out how to do a download to disk.